# How to associate a telegram user with user in my system

Tags: telegram, telegram-api

I have a membership website, and I want to add a telegram group for members, but be able to remove people from the group if they stop being a member.

I can't figure out how to associate the users on telegram with my users via the Telegram API.

The existing Membership bots for Telegram aren't helpful as they create new users, and I can't use them with the existing members of my web app.

Is this even possible?